# Single selection of Radio Button in android application

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have a couple of radio buttons on a page in my android application, I was wondering if anyone knew how to limit the user's selection to only one radio button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) in which user can select only one RadioButton

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure ur radio button are all inside radio group. The it should allow to only select one value. Example:

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```